# Flutter Circular Progress Indicator

Tags: flutter, flutter-circularprogressindicator

After exiting the PDF my circular progress indicator appears.

> I used a method named show Loader Dialog for displaying progress
> indicator and it works but even after displaying PDF and exiting it ,
> the circular progress indicator appears but i don't want to display this progress
> indicator on exiting the PDF.

Can anyone help me in this? I have following codes and pictures for your understanding.

[image: Code]

[image: code]

**Displaying PDF**
[image]

**After displaying PDF and upon exit progress indicator appears**
[image]

Comment: Can you please help me where should i include that Navigator.pop() in my code . I have my codes displayed above . I used open PDF method to open PDF and display..

Answer (score 0):

after opening the pdf put Navigator.pop() for closing the dialog might help if not let me know

Comment: Can you please help me where should i include that Navigator.pop() in my code . I have my codes displayed above . I used open PDF method to open PDF and display..